# Парсинг sql условного выражения в массив

Tags: javascript, sql

У меня есть строка

```
let str='(`id`=3) and (`filter`=\'test\' or (`filter`=\'1\' and `name`=\'2\'))'
```

Мне нужно чтобы строка превратилась в такой массив

```
let arr=[['id','=', '3'], 'and', [['filter','=', 'test'],
                                  'or', 
                                  [['filter','=', '1'],
                                   'and',
                                   ['name', '=', 'i']]]]
```

Я сделал это

```
  let str = "((`id`=3) and (`filter`='te\\\'st' or (`filter`='1' and `name`='2')))";
  let expression = [];
  let i = 0;
  let level = 0;
  let result = matches(str, /'(\\.|[^'])*'/ig, i, 't');
  let text = result.text;
  let phrase = parseSQL(result.result, level, expression);

  console.log({phrase, text, expression});
  console.log(getArray(expression));

  function parseSQL(str, level, expression) {
    let j = 0;
    let result = matches(str, /\([^()]+\)/gi, j, `e${level}_`);
    let phrase = result.result;
    expression.push(result.text);
    if (result.result.match(/\(/)) {
      phrase = parseSQL(result.result, level + 1, expression);
    }
    return phrase;
  }

  function matches(str, regex, i, letter) {
    let result = str.replace(regex, function () {
      return `$${letter}${i++}`;
    });
    let text = str.match(regex);
    return {result, text};
  }
```

У меня есть массив в котором есть ключи с уровнем, по которым я смогу собрать нужный вложенный массив, только не могу придумать как это сделать

Comment: Для начала вам надо сделать определитель типа каждой лексемы. Что бы отличать значения от имен колонок и от операторов. Все возможные операторы надо будет где то описать и указать какие аргументы и в каком количестве они принимают. Что бы разобрать `id between 1 and 45` или `id IN(1, 6, 10)` и даже `id=case when X=7 or X=8 then 45 else 55 end`. Потом определиться что с подзапросами `id IN(select x from tab ....)`. В общем это называется "синтаксический анализ" и ответ "как это сделать" займет не одну страницу. Лучше воспользоваться литературой, например "Книга дракона"

Comment: Кстати, лексический анализатор (который у вас сделан) надо будет то же дорабатывать. Например в идентификаторах могут быть пробелы, если он в обратных апострофах. И двойные кавычки в общем то допустимы в SQL (правда в разных диалектах по разному)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь работает как нужно, вдруг кому понадобиться

```
  let str = "((`id`='3') and (`filter`='te\\\'st' or (`filter`='1' and `name`='2')))";
  let expression = [];
  let i = 0;
  let level = 0;
  let result = getMatches(str, /'(\\.|[^'])*'/ig, i, 't');
  let text = result.text;
  let phrase = encryptExpression(result.result, level, expression);
  console.log({phrase, text, expression});

  let position = phrase.match(/\$e(\d)_(\d)/);
  let newArr = expression[position[1]][position[2]];

  newArr = getArray(expression, text, position, newArr);
  newArr = compareValues(newArr);
  console.log(newArr);

  function encryptExpression(str, level, expression) {
    let j = 0;
    let result = getMatches(str, /\([^()]+\)/gi, j, `e${level}_`);
    let phrase = result.result;
    expression.push(result.text);
    if (result.result.match(/\(/)) {
      phrase = encryptExpression(result.result, level + 1, expression);
    }
    return phrase;
  }

  function getMatches(str, regex, i, letter) {
    let result = str.replace(regex, function () {
      return `$${letter}${i++}`;
    });
    let text = str.match(regex);
    return {result, text};
  }

  function getArray(expression, text, position, newArr) {
    if (newArr.match(/([^(]+)\s+(and|or|not)\s+([^)]+)/i)) {
      newArr = newArr.match(/([^(]+)\s+(and|or|not)\s+([^)]+)/i).slice(1);

      for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (newArr[i].match(/\$e(\d)_(\d)/)) {
          position = newArr[i].match(/\$e(\d)_(\d)/);
          if (expression[position[1]][position[2]].charAt(0) === '('
            && expression[position[1]][position[2]].charAt(expression[position[1]][position[2]].length - 1) === ')') {
            newArr[i] = expression[position[1]][position[2]].substring(1, expression[position[1]][position[2]].length - 1)
          }
        }
        newArr[i] = getArray(expression, text, position, newArr[i]);

        if (typeof(newArr[i]) !== 'object') {
          if (newArr[i].match(/`(.*)`\s*(=|>|<|>=|<=|like|!=)\s*(\$t\d+)/i)) {
            newArr[i] = newArr[i].match(/`(.*)`\s*(=|>|<|>=|<=|like|!=)\s*(\$t\d+)/i).slice(1);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return newArr;
  }

  function compareValues(newArr) {
    if (newArr instanceof Array) {
      for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        if (!(newArr[i] instanceof Array)) {
          if (newArr[i].match(/\$t(\d+)/)) {
            newArr[i] = text[newArr[i].match(/\$t(\d+)/)[1]];
          }
        }
        newArr[i] = compareValues(newArr[i]);
      }
    }
    return newArr;
  }
```